# Integral pdf is not 1. I don’t know what’s wrong

Tags: probability, self-study

I differentiated cdf to find pdf and then integrated it, but the result is not 1. What’s wrong with my calculation?

CDF
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
0&x<1\\
\dfrac{x^2-2x+2}{2}&1\le x<2\\
1&x\ge2
\end{cases}$$
PDF
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x<1\\ x-1&1\le x<2\\0&x\ge 2\end{cases}$$
However,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx&=\int_1^2(x-1)dx\\&=\bigg[\frac12x^2-x\bigg]^2_1=\frac 12
\end{align*}

Comment: Please add the self-study tag & read its wiki. Also, please use math typsetting https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference it is easier to read, accessible to people with screen readers, and makes your question more likely to get useful responses. // To get un-stuck, try drawing a diagram of the pdf and cdf.

Comment: As always: *plot the CDF* before doing any calculations with it.  You will catch all sorts of subtleties that otherwise would result in erroneous answers.

Answer (score 11):

Look at the CDF carefully.  What is it's value at $x=1$?

You may have copied the CDF incorrectly, but if you do have the correct version then there is a point mass of $\frac12$ at $x=1$ which you have not accounted for in your PDF.  So with a point mass of $\frac12$ at $x=1$ and the area under the curve of $\frac12$, together they sum to 1.

Answer (score 5):

You should write $F(x),$ not $F(X).$ Capital $X$ refers to the random variable; the lower-case $x$ is any of the numbers that could be the input to this function.

The problem is that the distribution whose c.d.f. appears below is partly a discrete distribution.
$$
\begin{cases}0&x<1\\\dfrac{x^2-2x+2}{2}&1\le x<2\\1&x\ge2\end{cases}
$$
You have $F(1) = \frac{1^2-2\cdot1+2} 2= \frac 12$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x~\uparrow~1} F(x) = 0.$ That is a discontinuity in the c.d.f. That means that $\Pr(X=1)=1/2.$ When an isolated point has probability more than $0,$ the distribution is partly discrete.

Comment: (By "isolated" I don't mean what the term means in topology; I only mean that it's just one point.)